# Condition for existence of mle with a cauchy distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, maximum-likelihood, parameter-estimation

I'm solving some problem from statistical theory about maximum likelihood estimater.

Suppose $X_1,...,X_n$ are independent samples from $f(x;\alpha,\beta)$. ($n$ is an odd number.)

$$
f(x;\alpha,\beta) = \frac{1}{\pi\beta\Big[1+\big(\frac{x-\alpha}{\beta}\big)^2\Big]}, \alpha \in \mathbb{R}, \beta \in (0,\infty).
$$

When does maximum likelihood estimater of $\alpha, \beta$ exist?

Comment: So what is the likelihood, and what happened when you tried to maximise it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_distribution#Estimation_of_parameters is worth reading

Comment: @Henry I understand a little bit that the condition occurs during solve first derivative equations, but I'm still confused about one thing. My problem that I post is a practice from my statistics course. Why 'n' has to be an odd number? I can't see any need for get the condition about existence of mle.

Comment: Perhaps when $n$ is odd in a question it is easy to define the median, and an  $n$-degree polynomial has at least one real root.  I am not sure either matters here

Comment: @Henry Thanks for help.